# Need help adding Items into an array of linked lists

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, hashtable

I'm supposed to make a Hashtable from scratch and it's supposed to be an array of linked lists. I had to make my own Linked List class (in my code), and my own class for the items in the lists (DataItem, in the code).

I need help with my add(word) function. I'm supposed to add a DataItem into the array of linked lists at an index found using my hash function(I can get the index just fine).

I put my code below. Everything is bug-free and the add method "works", but it's not implementing the Linked List class that I made. instead of just putting a dataitem into the array at each index, I'm supposed to put the first link of a linked list, and put the dataitem in there. When there's a collision(like when I added carkcel), I'm supposed to add it to the next link in the linked list. Can I get some help with this? I don't know how to use linked lists at all.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashTable{

   private int tableSize = 97;

   //the LinkedList class I made
   public class LinkedList {
      private LinkedList next;  
      private final DataItem word;

      public LinkedList(DataItem word, LinkedList next) {
         this.word = word;
         this.next = next;
      }
   }


   public class DataItem {

      String word;
      int count;        // occurrence count of this word

       public DataItem(String word) {
          this.word = word;
          this.count = 1;
       }

    }



   /*A constructor, which takes no parameters and creates an empty hash table.*/     
   DataItem[] table = new DataItem[97];


   //My hash function.
   public int hash(String word){
   int index = 0;
      for(int i = 0;i < word.length(); i++){
         index += word.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1;     
      }   
      index = (((17 + word.length()) + index) * 17) % tableSize; 
      return index;
   }



   /*This method must search for word in the hash table, if it finds word, 
   it must increment the word’s occurrence count; if it does not find the word, 
   it must insert it into the hash table, giving it an initial occurrence count of 1.*/

   public void add(String word){

      //convert word to all lowercase
      word = word.toLowerCase();
      int index = hash(word);
      System.out.println("adding " + word + " at index " + index);
      DataItem newItem = new DataItem(word);      

      //search for the word at the index location's linked list.


         //if we don't find the word, add it to the beginning of the linked list;
         if(table[index] == null){
            table[index] = newItem;
            System.out.println(table[index]);
            return;
         }


         //if we find the word, increment the word's count. 
         if(table[index] != null){
            if(table[index].word  == word){
               table[index].count += 1;
               System.out.println(table[index]);
               return;
            }


            //if the word at index is different, add the new word to the next link in the linked list
            if(table[index].word != word){
               System.out.println("collision!");
               return;
            }         

         }

   }
```

When I run my tester program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      HashTable table = new HashTable();

      table.add("snap");
      table.add("crackle");
      table.add("pop");
      table.add("pop");
      table.add("carkcel");

   }

}
```

I get:

adding snap at index 43    'snap', 1

adding crackle at index 48    'crackle', 1

adding pop at index 72    'pop', 1

adding pop at index 72    'pop', 2

adding carkcel at index 48    collision!

Comment: Homework?? .....

Comment: You need a loop, to iterate through all the nodes of your linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the value to array index instead adding it to the linkedlist in that array index:Well, i can't see where you have created an array of linkedlist but i assume that you have linkedlists in table array.

```
       if(table[index] == null){
        table[index] = newItem;
        System.out.println(table[index]);
        return;
        }
```

You should call add method of linkedlist  like this:

```
    if(table[index].get() == null){
        table[index].add(newItem);
        System.out.println(table[index]);
        return;
     }
```

This algorithm is called seperate-chaining . You can find here how it works A book written by [Kevin Wayne & Robert Sedgewick.](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/) You an also find videos about it on youtube that's the reason i recommend you.

Here is the way to create a linkedlist in an array:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < table.length;i++){
     table[i] = new LinkedList(null,null);
  }
```

After this you can call method of add and get by using index.

Comment: That looks great. I thought my line DataItem[] table = new DataItem[97]; created the array of linked lists but looking back on it I see that it doesn't, so I have to try to find out how to do that.